# Gulp tasks appear to be running twice, instead of once

Tags: javascript, terminal, gulp

## Problem

My gulp tasks seem to be running twice instead of once, trying to fix thatI think some have suggested that the culprit might lie in the default task in `Gulpfile.js`

### Gulpfile.js

```
// Include Gulp
var gulp = require('gulp');

// All of your plugins
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload');
var minify = require('gulp-minify-css');
var notify = require('gulp-notify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');

// Compile CSS, Autoprefix
gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return gulp.src('assets/css/style.scss')
    .pipe(sass({ style: 'expanded' }))
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css'))
    // .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    // .pipe(minify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css'))
    .pipe(notify({ message: "Watson: I've organized your files for you." }));
});

// Lint, Concatenate and Minify JavaScript
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src('assets/js/scripts.js')
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
    // .pipe(concat('scripts.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/js'))
    // .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    // .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/js'))
    .pipe(notify({ message: "Watson: I've done your dirty laundry." }));
});

// Watch files for changes
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('assets/js/*.js', ['scripts', 'styles']);
    gulp.watch('assets/css/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
});

// Default Task
gulp.task('default', function() {
    gulp.start('styles', 'scripts', 'watch');
});
```

### Terminal

```
[18:53:57] Using gulpfile ~/Desktop/Projects/legislature/Gulpfile.js
[18:53:57] Starting 'default'...
[18:53:57] Starting 'styles'...
[18:53:57] Starting 'scripts'...
[18:53:58] Starting 'watch'...
[18:53:58] Finished 'watch' after 26 ms
[18:53:58] Finished 'default' after 49 ms
[18:53:58] gulp-notify: [Gulp notification] Watson: I've organized your files for you.
[18:53:58] Finished 'styles' after 262 ms
[18:53:58] gulp-notify: [Gulp notification] Watson: I've done your dirty laundry.
[18:53:58] Finished 'scripts' after 256 ms
[18:53:58] Starting 'scripts'...
[18:53:58] Starting 'styles'...
[18:53:58] gulp-notify: [Gulp notification] Watson: I've done your dirty laundry.
[18:53:58] Finished 'scripts' after 232 ms
[18:53:58] gulp-notify: [Gulp notification] Watson: I've organized your files for you.
[18:53:58] Finished 'styles' after 232 ms
```

Comment: nice notify message.

Answer (score 1):

Your `scripts` task writes to the same folder that `watch` task is watching. Watch then runs the `scripts` and `styles` tasks as specified:

```
gulp.watch('assets/js/*.js', ['scripts', 'styles']);
```

Comment: How do I make it so it only runs once?

Comment: Don't run styles task when js files change?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is: you have two identical line that saves the file and triggers twice.

In your **scripts** task

```
.pipe(gulp.dest('assets/js'))
```

**Other possible problem for newcomers.**
I write here my experience maybe helps somebody.

I use Dropbox for my project and work there. When Dropbox is open, tasks run twice because Dropbox detects file change and does something. Specially Typescript files, i don't know why.