# Why is Gulp running the same task twice?

Tags: gulp

I am having a similar issue as the [question posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377303/gulp-tasks-appear-to-be-running-twice-instead-of-once) but none of the answers given there apply to my situation.

When I run the one and only task defined in my Gulpfile.js file it is getting executed twice.

I am using Gulp version 4.0.2

This is the contents of my Gulpfile.js file:

```
const { src, dest, watch, series, parallel } = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const rename = require('gulp-rename');
const postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const cssnano = require('cssnano');    
const files = {
    bootstrapSrcPath: 'bootstrap-sass/bootstrap.scss',
    bootstrapDstPath: 'Test'
};

exports.scssTask = series(
    scssTaskFunc
);

function scssTaskFunc() {  
    return src(files.bootstrapSrcPath)            
        .pipe(sass({ style: 'expanded' }))
        .pipe(dest(files.bootstrapDstPath))
        .pipe(postcss([autoprefixer(), cssnano()]))
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(dest(files.bootstrapDstPath));
}
```

This is the command I am running in the CMD prompt and the results:

```
C:\Users\myUser\source\repos\myProject> cmd.exe / c gulp - b "C:\Users\myUser\source\repos\myProject" --color--gulpfile "C:\Users\myUser\source\repos\myProject\Gulpfile.js" scssTask
[16: 10: 15]Using gulpfile ~\source\repos\myProject\Gulpfile.js
[16: 10: 15]Starting 'scssTask'...
[16: 10: 15] Starting 'scssTaskFunc'...
[16: 10: 17] Finished 'scssTaskFunc' after 1.7 s
[16: 10: 17]Finished 'scssTask' after 1.71 s
Process terminated with code 0.
```

It works and the output file is what I expect but it seems like a waste to do it twice.

This is the what gulp shows for tasks:

```
C:\Users\myUser\source\repos\myProject> gulp--tasks
[15: 57: 29]Tasks for ~\source\repos\myProject\Gulpfile.js
[15: 57: 29]└─┬ scssTask
[15: 57: 29]└─┬ <series>
[15:57:29]     └── scssTaskFunc
```

**Why is it running the task twice,  once as the 'scssTask' and the second as the 'scssTaskFunc'?**

Btw, this is my first attempt at gulp so I apologize if this is a derp question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your task isn't running twice, it just seems like it does because you're using `gulp.series`.

`gulp.series` and `gulp.parallel` are normally used to combine and compose tasks into larger operations. If, for example, you'd have a `jsTaskFunc` as well, you could create a task `build` like so:

```js
exports.build = parallel(scssTaskFunc, jsTaskFunc);
```

and running `gulp build` would log something like this in your terminal:

```
[09:42:12] Starting 'build'...
[09:42:12] Starting 'scssTaskFunc'...
[09:42:12] Starting 'jsTaskFunc'...
[09:42:12] Finished 'scssTaskFunc' after 93 ms
[09:42:12] Finished 'jsTaskFunc' after 94 ms
[09:42:12] Finished 'build' after 111 ms
```

Something similar is happening now due to your use of `gulp.series`, because `scssTask` runs `scssTaskFunc` as a dependent task, but `scssTask` and `scssTaskFunc` are strictly speaking not the same task. Nothing gets run twice.

To avoid confusion, and because `gulp.series` isn't necessary, simply do:

```js
exports.scssTask = scssTaskFunc;
```